# project raised exception class EIdInterceptPropInvalid with message "Intercept value is not valid".Process stopped

Tags: c++, exception, get

I have issue in download file using Get() in Borland C++ Builder 6.
Have the following code which executes on clock of a Button.

TFileStream* fs = new TFileStream("E:\\someplace.exe", fmCreate);
Download->Get(Edit1->Text, fs);

I see the exception "project raised exception class EIdInterceptPropInvalid with message 'Intercept value is not valid'.Process stopped".I can build the code with zero errors.But when tried to run the application and click the Button I see this exception.Could not find any related information in Google.
Please help me in fixing this exception.

thanks in advance.
Madhu Kondur
kondur.madhu@gmail.com

Comment: Try `"E:\\someplace.exe"` (or was that a typo in your post?)

Comment: That was a typo..!Updated now.

Comment: From [here](http://www.e-iter.net/Knowledge/Indy9/000397.html) I read: "This can occur if you attempt to use a TIdHTTP component access a secure HTTP site (HTTPS) while the TIdHTTP's Intercept property is not set to a TIdSSLConnectionIntercept descendant.".  Is that any help?  My best effort.

Comment: Thank you @PaulSanders ..But where can we set Intercept property.

Comment: That I don't know, sorry, but at least you have something to go on.  You'll have to have a nose around.